# Joining rows in Acces under specific conditions

Tags: ms-access

I am working in access 2010 I have a table which has the following format:

`ID   BOORP   BEGIN_DIEPTE   EIND_DIEPTE   TEXTUUR1
 1   148000        0             10          ZK
 2   148000        20            60          ZK
 3   148000        60            80          MK
 4   148000        80            110         MK
 5   148000        110           130         ZK
 6   148000        130           160         -
 7   148000        160           220         ZZL
 8   148000        220           250         -
 9   148000        250           300         MK
 10  148001        0             20          ZK
 11  148001        20            40          -
 12  148001        40            210         ZZL
 13  148001        210           310         ZZL`

What i want is to join certain rows which have the same texture under the following conditions:

1) rows must have the same BOORP in order to be merged

2) only consecutive rows may be merged

The result should look like this:

`ID   BOORP   BEGIN_DIEPTE   EIND_DIEPTE   TEXTUUR1
 1   148000        0             60          ZK
 3   148000        60            110         MK
 5   148000        110           130         ZK
 6   148000        130           160         -
 7   148000        160           220         ZZL
 8   148000        220           250         -
 9   148000        250           300         MK
 10  148001        0             20          MK
 11  148001        20            40          -
 12  148001        40            310         ZZL`

It is especially the 2nd condition i'm having problem with.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a complex task as an SQL-only solution.
If you want to do it in one query, you can use the following solution (tested on your sample data):

```sql
SELECT e.ID, e.BOORP, e.BEGIN_DIEPTE, e.EINDDIEPTE As EIND_DIEPTE, e.TEXTUUR1 
FROM
(
    SELECT a.ID, a.BOORP, a.BEGIN_DIEPTE, IIF(b.ID Is Null, a.EIND_DIEPTE, b.EIND_DIEPTE) AS EINDDIEPTE, a.TEXTUUR1, b.ID As IDJoined
    FROM TestTable a
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT c.*, (SELECT Max(d.ID) FROM TestTable d WHERE d.ID < c.ID) As PreviousID
            FROM TestTable c
        ) As b
    ON b.PreviousID = a.ID AND b.BOORP = a.BOORP AND a.TEXTUUR1 = b.TEXTUUR1
) AS e
WHERE e.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT b.ID
    FROM TestTable a
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT c.*, (SELECT Max(d.ID) FROM TestTable d WHERE d.ID < c.ID) As PreviousID
            FROM TestTable c
        ) As b
    ON b.PreviousID = a.ID AND b.BOORP = a.BOORP AND a.TEXTUUR1 = b.TEXTUUR1
)
```

It's quite a lot of subqueries, and a bit too much to explain in depth. Simply put, the most inner subquery (query `b`) `LEFT JOIN`s on equal `BOORP` and `TEXTUUR1` and where the ID is the previous ID, then the outer subquery (query `e`) takes the result, and removes all the entries that have been joined with another entry.

Note that this joins 2 entries together, not more than that. If you want to join more than 2 entries together, you can just run a similar query on the result of this one.